# TypeError: unable to acces a wrapped function with double pointer argument

Tags: c++, python, swig

Im very new to swig and got a strange TypeError when i access a function with an double pointer as argument.

Here are my files:

Example.hpp

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLE_HPP
#define _EXAMPLE_HPP

class Example {
public:
    void test_cc(char * c0, char * c1);
    void test_cd(char * c0, double d0);
    void test_cdp(char * c0, double * d0);
};

#endif // _EXAMPLE_HPP
```

Example.cpp

```
#include "Example.hpp"

void Example::test_cc(char * c0, char * c1) {}
void Example::test_cd(char * c0, double d0) {}
void Example::test_cdp(char * c0, double * d0) {}
```

Example.i

```
%module Example
%{
#include "Example.hpp"
%}

#include "Example.hpp"
```

and finally my testfile test_Example.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Example

E = Example.Example()

E.test_cc("Hello","World");
E.test_cd("Hello",42);
E.test_cdp("Hello",42);
```

When i run ./test_Example.py, i get the Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_Example.py", line 9, in <module>
    E.test_cdp("Hello",42);
  File "Example.py", line 77, in test_cdp
    def test_cdp(self, *args): return _Example.Example_test_cdp(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'Example_test_cdp', argument 3 of type 'double *'
```

Accessing the function test_cc works, test_cd also ... why not test_cdp?

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is actually in:

```
void test_cd(char * c0, double * d0);
```

and that your argument should be a `double`, not a `double*`.

**In reference to your comment**

Your code is:

```
E.test_cc("Hello","World");
E.test_cd("Hello",42);
```

Your prototypes are:

```
void test_cc(char * c0, char * c1);
void test_cd(char * c0, double d0);
```

"Hello" and "World" are string literals that decay to type const char*.  So, they are pointers.  When you pass c0 and c1 in test_cc its fine because it expects a pointer.

while c0 is a pointer in test_cd, d0 is not - d0 is of type double, NOT pointer-to-double.  So, you must pass in a pointer to a double instead.

You can do this by either creating a double on the stack and passing in its address:

```
double hi_mom = 83.2;
test_cd("some string" &hi_mom);
```

or by declaring a pointer and making it point to a stack variable, passing that in:

```
double hi_mom = 83.2;
double* ptr = &hi_mom;
test_cd("some string", ptr);
```

or by declaring a pointer pointing to dynamic memory and passing that in:

```
double* ptr = new double(83.2);
test_cd("some string", ptr);
delete ptr;
```

Though I'd avoid the 3rd one if you can.

**Edit again...**

http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/c_extensions.html

shows a working example of how to call C code from python including passing a double.  Search for iterate_point in both the python and C code to see how it works.  You shouldn't have a pointer for the double, it should just be a normal double as said earlier.

Comment: I want to access the c++ fcuntion test_cdp from python, not from c++.

Comment: Edited answer again... but it's what I said in the first place.  I provided a working example this time.

Comment: I want to pass a double*. Not a double. test_cd works but is not that what i want. iterate_point gets double, too. not double*.